# ERC20 token split

Tags: erc-20

I was wondering how a project can perform a token split (regarding the recent discussion in the YFI commnunity) as I could not find any information on this.

For example:
An ERC20 has a supply of 10.000. If I wanted to perform a 1:10 split, I would have a supply of 100.000 and thus a lower price per unit.

Thank you.